# Проблема с pyowm и библиотекой eel

Tags: python, html, jquery, python-3.x, pyowm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Погода</title>

    <script src="eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head> 
<body>

<input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Введите название страны и города..." required=""value="Нью-Йорк, США">

<button id="show">Узнать погоду</button>

<div id="info"></div>

<script src ="https//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     // тут пишем JS код для вызова Python функций

    async function display_weather() {
        Let place = document.getElementByID('location').value;

        // вызываем функцию get_weather из Python кода
        Let res = await eel.get_weather(place)();
        document.getElementByID('info').innerHTML = res;
    }

    jQuery('#show').on('click', function() {
        // при клике на кнопку, отображаем погоду
        display_weather();
       });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

при нажатии на кнопку "Узнать погоду" в созданном приложении ничего не происходит, хотя должно писать температуру.Я новичок, надеюсь на помощь

Comment: Перебейте заново в 11 строчке `w = ...` пробелы или табуляции, что там у вас в остальных строчках, сделайте в этой строке те же символы отступа в том же кол-ве.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло. Но теперь другая проблема, при нажатии на кнопку "Узнать погоду" в созданном приложении ничего не происходит, хотя должно писать температуру. Прикрепил html код в описании. Надеюсь на помощь, я новичок.

Comment: Зря вы вопрос переделываете, комментарии и ответы становятся неактуальными. В будущем так не делайте. Хотя так то вопрос про неправильные отступы тут 100500 раз уже задавали и он ценности не несёт, так что в этот раз можете так делать, но в будущем не меняйте вопрос, а задавайте новый после того, как старый вопрос решился.

Comment: А так навскидку - навтыкайте `alert`-ов в код, а лучше откройте консоль разработчика в `Chrome`, посмотрите, нет ли там ошибок JS, ну и пройдитесь отладчиком по JS функции.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в 11 строчке кода, в которой объект 'w' ты добавил не метод с данными, а пустое значение.
Замени

```
    'w = observation.weather'
```

на

```
    'w = observation.get_weather()'
```

Comment: Всё равно та же ошибка (

Comment: Думаю, что ошибка в чем-то другом